# Updating Strapi Docker package.json

Tags: docker, npm, package.json, strapi

I'm in the process of learning about Docker by trying to containerify a Strapi CMS. The default Docker image (https://github.com/strapi/strapi-docker) works well enough as a starting point, but I'm trying to add a couple packages to the Strapi instance for my needs (adding in Azure storage account support using https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-provider-upload-azure-storage). As I'm new to Docker, I'm having a hard time figuring how to make the container install that package as part of the Docker run process.

I see that the strapi/base image Dockerfile contains this line referencing a package.json file:

> COPY ./package.json ./

I'm assuming that's where I would add a reference to the packages I'm wanting to install so that later on they are installed by npm, but I'm not sure where that package.json file is located, let alone how to modify it.

Any help on figuring out how to install that package during the Docker run process is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that strapi-docker uses a script to build images and not just the Docker files in the repo (bin/build.js). I also discovered that docker-entrypoint.sh is where the dependency installation is happening, so I added a couple of npm install statements after the check for the node_modules directory. Doing this allowed me to successfully add the desired packages to my Docker container.

Comment: So you forked the strapi-docker repo, modified the shell script, built a local image and referenced this instead? That's what it took just to update packages?!

Comment: I'm no strapi/docker expert but modifying the shell script doesn't sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I followed some of the advice from the Docker team here:

https://www.docker.com/blog/keep-nodejs-rockin-in-docker/

After performing the initial setup with `docker-compose` and the `strapi/strapi` image, I was able to install additional dependencies directly inside the container using `docker-compose run <service name> yarn add <package>`.

I opted for this route since I was having trouble installing the [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) library - it has different dependencies/binaries for Linux and Mac OS. This approached worked well for me, but the downside is that you can't mount your `node_modules` folder as a volume and it may take a little longer to install packages in the container.

Comment: It the reason you can't mount your modules because of the duplicate modules error? Is there no way around this? Do you have a link to some more in-depth information about why that is the case? 

The other option is to add `command: bash -c "yarn && yarn develop"` to your docker-compose file (works with volume mounted). Installing just 1 package takes like 10minutes though...... If someone can provide a better/FASTER way I will love them forever.